# powershell parse logfile when updated

Tags: powershell, text-parsing, robocopy

I have a script running that mirrors two directories and updates a log file about what happens between the two directories. I want to parse this log file to get updates as they come in (while the script is running) and I want these to send me an email of what has changed, like a notification. Also - I don't want to get notified about the same bit of info more than once if possible?

I'm unsure on how I would go about doing this after reading through some of the command lists online.

**Tldr;**
*Really all i'm looking to do is when a line is added to the Logfile, parse the file to get the updated line, without getting any of the other lines.*

Not all that strong with PowerShell so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can have PowerShell get each new line as it comes in by passing the `-Wait` parameter to `Get-Content`.  You can then pass that into a `Foreach-Object` scriptblock to perform whatever operation you need.

```
Get-Content $logfile -Tail 0 -Wait | foreach {
  "Another line was added: " + $_
}
```

The `-Tail N` argument causes `Get-Content` to only get the last N lines; in this case zero.  This causes it to skip everything already in the file, and only pass newly added lines to your script block.

Note: This cmdlet will continue running until you cancel it with Ctrl+C (or otherwise stop its PowerShell process), which makes it much better for use in an interactive prompt than in a script.

Comment: Thanks so much I've been looking for ages for this! would I pass the email script into the foreach to get it to email each new line to myself? then that would email each line as it comes in right?

Thanks again! :)

Comment: You would put commands inside the `foreach {...}` block.  Inside that block, the `$_` variable contains the full line that was added.

Comment: so i should email "$_"? as the body, as that contains the line? :)

Comment: That's a good start, but it depends entirely on what you want in your e-mail.  I'd probably build a string for the body that includes that line and some text explaining why my machine is sending me mail.  :)

Comment: ah yeah that would make more sense haha. I put the command into Powershell and i've got loads of errors like:

You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:1 char:7

Unexpected token 'Tail' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:8

Unexpected token '0' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:13

Unexpected token '-Wait' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:15

An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:1 char:21

Any idea why this is?

Comment: The `-Wait` parameter has some pitfalls you might need to be aware of. *<quote>but this requires the process writing to the file to open, append, close it before Get-Content will work. If the writing process never closes the file then it won't work which is not the case with tail -f.</quote>* taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4427285/52598)

Comment: @flanelman No idea what's causing those errors without seeing the exact command you entered.  You might be using [the wrong `foreach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29148614).

Comment: What modifications can be made to use this in a script?