# How to execute Windows command (Get-Content) from PowerShell in Windows Server

Tags: windows, powershell

My server is Windows Server. I would like to replicate the Unix `tail` command in Windows Server.

Unix Server: `tail -f test.txt`

PowerShell: `Get-Content test.txt`

How to execute in Windows Server?

Below command is not working:

```
powershell -File "Get-Content test.txt"
```

Error message:

> Unable to execute program 'powershell -File "\"Get-Content...

Any idea?

Comment: The command should fail with a different error. How exactly are you invoking it?

Comment: `powershell -File "myScript.ps1"` vs `powershell -Command "Get-Content test.txt"`

Comment: @briantist That too (and also add `-Tail` for following the file), but his error message suggests that for some reason his entire statement is interpreted as a single command.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers agreed; I wonder if this is being invoked through some other software

Answer (score 4):

`Get-Content` is not a file; it is a cmdlet. The `-file` parameter to Powershell.exe instructs Powershell to read the file supplied and execute the commands in it, as a script.

You can pass commands directly to Powershell by using the `-command` parameter; the parameter can be a quoted string, which is interpreted as a Powershell command. You would therefore want to use

```
powershell -command "Get-Content test.txt"
```

in the simplest case.

Note that Powershell.exe must be in your system path; if it is not, you would need to supply the full path to powershell, e.g.,

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "Get-Content text.txt"
```

This question is very similar - perhaps essentially identical - to [Unix tail equivalent command in Windows Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell); I would recommend reading that question and its answers as well.

Additionally, exploring the help for `Get-Content` will provide useful information.

Comment: Thanks Jeff Zeitlin. 

Working fine after setting full path of **powershell.exe without quotes**

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command Get-Content test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Working fine after setting **full path of powershell.exe and without any quotes**

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command Get-Content test.txt`

Answer (score -1):

Within a powershell window :

```
Get-Content test.txt
```

command returns :

> hello world.
>       i'm inside test.txt.
>       bye.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question; he is trying to execute the Get-Content cmdlet by invoking Powershell externally, and getting an error.