# How do you neatly tail a log file in VS Code alongside your executing Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I was originally looking for a way to have an open log file in VS Code update automatically as I watched it without installing an extension. I couldn't find an option to do that, and actually I think this answer works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

This answer describes how to tail a file in Powershell: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell#:~:text=For%20completeness%20I%27ll%20mention%20that%20Powershell%203.0%20now%20has%20a%20%2DTail%20flag%20on%20Get%2DContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell#:%7E:text=For%20completeness%20I%27ll%20mention%20that%20Powershell%203.0%20now%20has%20a%20%2DTail%20flag%20on%20Get%2DContent)

The summary of that is:
`Get-Content 'yourfile.log' -wait -tail 30`

In order to watch it, SPLIT your Terminal window in VS Code - terminals are listed to the right of the Terminal. Hover over your current terminal session in that list, choose SPLIT and then enter the get-content tail command of your log file in the new Terminal.

[image: Image of VS Code split terminal windows]