# Reading the last n lines from a huge text file

Tags: windows, r, file-io

I've tried something like this

```
file_in <- file("myfile.log","r")
x <- readLines(file_in, n=-100)
```

but I'm still waiting...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can imagine you have to wait pretty long. negative n values indicate to read to the end of file. If that file is 7.5 Gb, well...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd use `scan` for this, in case you know how many lines the log has :

```
scan("foo.txt",sep="\n",what="char(0)",skip=100)
```

If you have no clue how many you need to skip, you have no choice but to move towards either

- reading in everything and taking the last n lines (in case that's feasible),
- using `scan("foo.txt",sep="\n",what=list(NULL))` to figure out how many records there are, or
- using some algorithm to go through the file, keeping only the last n lines every time

The last option could look like :

```
ReadLastLines <- function(x,n,...){    
  con <- file(x)
  open(con)
  out <- scan(con,n,what="char(0)",sep="\n",quiet=TRUE,...)

  while(TRUE){
    tmp <- scan(con,1,what="char(0)",sep="\n",quiet=TRUE)
    if(length(tmp)==0) {close(con) ; break }
    out <- c(out[-1],tmp)
  }
  out
}
```

allowing :

```
ReadLastLines("foo.txt",100)
```

or

```
ReadLastLines("foo.txt",100,skip=1e+7)
```

in case you know you have more than 10 million lines. This can save on the reading time when you start having extremely big logs.

---

EDIT : In fact, I'd not even use R for this, given the size of your file. On Unix, you can use the [tail](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm) command. There is a windows version for that as well, somewhere in a toolkit. I didn't try that out yet though.

Comment: Really nice summary (+1)! I would add that counting the lines outside of R (e.g.: `wc` in Linux) could be a lot easier/faster. Other: I do not get the point in `while(1) {...}`. Will this loop ever end?

Comment: @daroczig : indeed, it never ends. Ugly hack, I know, but I use it more often if I have to check a condition somewhere in the middle of a loop. And indeed, I'd resort to other tools than R for this question, but this is how I'd do it in R.

Comment: @Joris Meys: thanks for your kind answer. Now I see the `break` part in your loop, somehow I overlooked it :) Sorry for bothering.

Comment: Do you know the windows version of `tail`?

Comment: @gd047 : Here you can find some info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command. But as said, I never tried it myself

Comment: `while(TRUE)` would be easier to understand - doesn't rely on internal coercion to logical.

Comment: @hadley : indeed, very right. It's the old Perl way I still use. Corrected and remembered.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with `read.table` by specifying the `skip` parameter. If your lines are not to be parsed to variables, specify the separator to be `'\n'` as @Joris Meys pointed out below, and also set `as.is=TRUE` to get character vectors instead of factors.

Small example (skipping the first 2000 lines):

```
df <- read.table('foo.txt', sep='\n', as.is=TRUE, skip=2000)
```

Comment: Nice hack, but don't forget to use as.is=T. It works if you set the sep="\n", eg : `read.table("foo.txt",sep="\n",as.is=T,skip=100)`

Comment: Thank you @Joris Meys, I have updated my answer based on your really helpful comment.

Comment: What if I don't know how many lines to skip? The file is about 7.5 GB. I was mistakenly thinking that using -n, readlines returns the last n lines. It reads everything and that's why it took so long.

Comment: @gd047: I would not let R count the number of lines of a 7.5 Gb textfile, I would use a fast dedicated software for this. I suppose counting the lines in R would take a lot of time, but using e.g. `wc` in Linux could parse the file in a few seconds. You could also call `wc` from R (see: `?system`) if using Linux.

Comment: @daroczig : for what it's worth, I'd use the `tail` command in linux : http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm

Comment: @Joris Meys: yes, very good point! I was not enough creative to diverge from R totally, just concentrating in finding out the number of lines fast and then do the rest in R :)

Answer (score 1):

As @JorisMeys already mentioned the unix command `tail` would be the easiest way to solve this problem. However I want to propose a `seek` based `R` solution that starts reading the file from the end of the file:

```
tailfile <- function(file, n) {
  bufferSize <- 1024L
  size <- file.info(file)$size

  if (size < bufferSize) {
    bufferSize <- size
  }

  pos <- size - bufferSize
  text <- character()
  k <- 0L

  f <- file(file, "rb")
  on.exit(close(f))

  while(TRUE) {
    seek(f, where=pos)
    chars <- readChar(f, nchars=bufferSize)
    k <- k + length(gregexpr(pattern="\\n", text=chars)[[1L]])
    text <- paste0(text, chars)

    if (k > n || pos == 0L) {
      break
    }

    pos <- max(pos-bufferSize, 0L)
  }

  tail(strsplit(text, "\\n")[[1L]], n)
}

tailfile(file, n=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read last n lines by following method

Step 1 - Open your file as your wish
`df <- read.csv("hw1_data.csv")`

Step 2 - Now use `tail` function to read n lines from last

`tail(df, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Some folks have said it already, but if you have a large log, it is most efficient to only read in what you need instead of reading it all into memory, then subsetting what you need.

For this, we use R's `system()` to run the Linux `tail` command.

#### Read the last 10 lines of the log:

```
system("tail path/to/my_file.log")
```

#### Read the last 2 lines of the log:

```
system("tail -n 2 path/to/my_file.log")
```

#### Read the last 2 lines of the log and capture the output in a character vector:

```
last_2_lines <- system("tail -n 2 path/to/my_file.log", intern = TRUE)
```

Answer (score -1):

For seeing the last few lines:

```
tail(file_in,100)
```