# R readLines read only last line of a file

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading the last n lines from a huge text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596107/reading-the-last-n-lines-from-a-huge-text-file)

I have created a connection to a file using

```
con=file(path_of_myfile)
```

Now I want to read only the last line without loading everything (it is a HUGE file).

I am trying to use

```
?readLines
```

with no success.

Any idea?

Comment: does R have anything like a *seek* function?

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596107/reading-the-last-n-lines-from-a-huge-text-file since the restriction to `n=1` here gives rise to potentially simpler solutions.  This is due to the fact that you typically have the last line available when you hit the end of the file.

Comment: @RockScience Have you tried `count.felds()`? Try `length(count.fields("foo.txt"))`. It should be platform independent, but it will probably be slower since it _counts fields_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are on Windows, download and install Duncan's [Rtools](http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/) which you would need anyways if you wanted to build R packages yourself.  (If you were on Linux then the only difference is that you would not need to download anything since `gawk` is already there.) Then issue this R command:

```
system("gawk 'END {print}' myfile", intern = TRUE)
```

Comment: I have an Error in system... : 
  'gawk' not found Do I have to add something to the PATH?

Comment: @Rockcience, Assuming Rtools is in `C:\Rtools`, add `C:\Rtools\bin` to your path.  Alternately, use `Rgui.bat` from `http://batchfiles.googlecode.com` to start R (in place of `Rgui.exe`) in which case it will automatically add the required directory to your path for the duration of the R session without you having to change anything.

Answer (score 5):

If you're running on a unix-like system you could possibly use `wc` to count lines and use `scan()` in R with the `skip` argument:

```
lastline <- function(filename) {
  ## filename is of mode character
  out <- system(sprintf("wc -l %s",filename),intern=TRUE)
  n <- as.integer(sub(sprintf("[ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]%s",filename),"\\1",out))
  print(n)
  scan(filename,what="",skip=n-1,nlines=1,sep="\n",quiet=TRUE)
}

> lastline("myfile")
```

Comment: I would love to run my scripts on Unix but I unfortunately work in a Microsoft friendly environment...

Comment: +1 for `system( "wc -l")` recipe.