# How to import last 100 rows using read.csv() in R

Tags: r, csv, import

Hi I've a huge file and i want to import only the last 100 rows from that file.
How can we do that using read.csv() or any alternative?

Comment: If you're concerned about speed, then try `fread` from "data.table" and then just extract the rows you need. Similarly, you can use `sqldf`. If you're on a Unix system, you have access to the `tail` command that could be useful.

Comment: I know we can use os specific commands but i'm looking for a work around in R itself!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The package R.utils has a function called countLines(). You could do:

```
l2keep <- 10
nL <- countLines("your.csv")
df <- read.csv("your.csv", header=FALSE, skip=nL-l2keep)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a *nix system, you are better off using the `tail -n 100` command to take the last 100 rows. Anything implemented in R would be slower and potentially much slower is your file is truly huge.

If you are using Windows, you may want to take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command).

Comment: ya that's true. So what you are telling is that using some windows function to get the last 100 rows put it in a file and then import into R?

Comment: Pretty much. You can do `seek()` and other "fancy" stuff in R but good luck finding something that is as fast or as simple.

Answer (score 2):

Improvement on @lauratboyer's answer if you want to include headers too:

```
# read headers only
column_names <- as.vector(t(read.csv("your.csv", header=FALSE, colClasses='character', nrows=1)))

# then last n lines
l2keep <- 10
nL <- R.utils::countLines("your.csv")
df <- read.csv("your.csv", header=FALSE, col.names=column_names, skip=nL-l2keep)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `nrows` and `skip` arguments in `read.csv`. E.g. if you have a file with 10000 rows and you would only like to import the last 100 rows you could try this:

```
read.csv("yourfile.csv",nrows=100,skip=9900)
```

But if it is speed you want, you're probably better off with the solutions given by @Ananda Mahto and @ktdrv

Comment: thanks for the reply.But the problem is my file size is so huge that i'm unable to determine the total number of rows records.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way that works for me - use `fread` to read large files while setting `select = 1` so that only the first column is read. Then use `fread` again to read data from the desired rows. `Fread` is much faster than `read.csv` or other similar variants. More on `fread` vs `read.csv` here: [Reason behind speed of fread in data.table package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424361/reason-behind-speed-of-fread-in-data-table-package-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

*Read file, use tail function* 
   a<-read.csv('c:/..')
    tail(a,100L)

Answer (score -2):

give appropriate **skip** parameter in read.csv()

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP's question.  They want to *read from a file* only the last 100 rows.  Your answer assumes the data set has already been read.

Comment: This reply is useless. It's just a bad copy of @Rob's reply (who replied first). For the record, I am not criticizing Rob's answer, but only this B K's reply