# From the list of data frame select particular columns in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, lapply

I have multiple CSV files say 2, and I want to extract the specific column from each file.

```
filenames <- list.files("path")
for(iter in 1:length(filenames)){
  print(filenames[iter])
  my_csv=read.csv(filenames[iter])
```

Where, csv1 and csv2 contains columns a1,a2,a3,a4 and b1,b2,b3,b4 respectively. Now I want to fetch column a1 from csv1 and b2 from csv2 where csv number (csv**1**(1 in this case) matches with coulmn name (a1 in this case)). Likewise b2 from csv2(csv**2** matches with colummn name b2.

Comment: Are files named "csv1.csv"?

Comment: @PoGibas, Yes!!

Comment: So from file csv1.csv you want to extract first column, or column that has "1" in it?

Comment: @PoGibas, I want to extract a column "a.filename" (in this case a.csv1).

Comment: so files are named: a.csv1, b.csv2, etc?

Comment: Files are named as csv1.csv, csv2.csv. And  every csv contains around 100 columns. But I want to fetch only those columns named as a.csv1(column name in csv1 file), a.csv2(column name in csv2 file).     a is common in every file. I have 3 files in total.    Final output of columns should be a.csv1,a.csv2,a.csv3.

Comment: Ok, hope that I got what you want, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading in csv files I strongly recommend using `fread` from `data.table` package (More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428572/1286528)).

```
library(data.table)
fileCSV <- list.files(pattern = "csv$")
# This function extracts i column from the csv file
# It doesn't look into colnames
getCSVcolumn <- function(FILE) {
    i <- gsub("csv|\\.", "", FILE)
    foo <- fread(FILE)
    foo[, paste0("V", i), with = FALSE]
}
res <- sapply(fileCSV, getCSVcolumn)
res <- do.call("cbind", res)
colnames(res) <- gsub("\\..*","", colnames(res))
```

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas. It is working. But I am getting all the columns in one data frame. I want separate data frame for each column.

Comment: Just don't use anything after apply part