# Live php Error logs on Windows

Tags: php, logging

Is there a program or a way to view php error log live on windows. I need something that watches the error log and when errors are logged it will display the list. Something similar to developer tools in your browser, although, it does not need to be nested within browser.

Comment: Is it a problem to watch apache logs?

Comment: I was looking to watch it live, as the errors come in. The answer below is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post if you have windows powershell, equiv to tail on linux
https://stackoverflow.com/a/188126/1136734

Comment: This is what I was looking for, although you have mistakenly posted the link twice.

Comment: That was to make sure you got it ;-) Ill edit it now :-)