# How to stream display a text file as another program updates it?

Tags: c++, windows, text, windows-7

What is the best way to display the contents of a text (.txt) as it updates?  The log is updated by a C++ program that outputs log/error messages to it, and the file persists between (and is present before) runs.

Currently, I just keep it open in Nopepad++, which asks to update whenever it detects changes were made.  But it requires window focus to do that, which makes debugging some situations difficult and tedius.

Comment: Under linux we have the `tail -f` purposed for such. I don't know if there's a windows system tool equivalent. At least MinGW MSys supports this command.

Comment: Also see [Looking for a windows equivalent of the unix tail command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command)

Comment: I ended up following πάντα ῥεῖ's link, and downloaded the unix tail command.  It's better than expected!  I can stuff `tail.exe -f -n20 filename.txt` into the build script and it automatically comes up when I begin debugging

Answer (score -1):

The Document Monitor Plugin does not require focus.

It can be installed via the plugin manager (just search for "Document Monitor").

After installed choose Plugins->Document Monitor->Start to Monitor, to update all documents every 3 seconds.

Source:http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/auto-refresh-all-opened-notepad-documents-to-view-changes-document-monitor/