# How do I read the last line of a file with a bare Perl on Windows?

Tags: perl

I need to read only the last line of a file, without using File:ReadBackwards module  as it is not installed on my remote server(windows) where I need to execute the script.
Kindly suggest the most efficient way to read only the last line.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command#comment5036679_187826

Comment: The most efficient way is to install the module that you're missing.

Comment: @DaveCross Thanks and I understand too but that is a remote server, not totally handled by me.

Comment: @simbabque sure that post make sense. But if I could have installed anything on machine I would have done the module itself

Comment: My link didn't point to any answer, but one specific comment that gives you a batch file.

Comment: @simbabque thats cool, Thanks, Will try that too. I thought you pointed to the marked answer of that question which said about installing GNU utilities. Sorry about that. Thanks again.

Comment: Nope. Linking to comments is a bit weird, but it appears at the very top of the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in windows. I don't know what are the inbuild command for windows but you try something like as follows

Iterate the file handler with while loop and store the output in variable then print it

```
open my $fh ,"<","file.txt";
my $last_line;
$last_line = $_,while (<$fh>);
print $last_line;
```

or else  try the follow but these are consume more memory.

```
open my $fh ,"<","file.txt" or die "error opening $!";
my @ar = <$fh>;
print $ar[-1];
```

Or else

```
open my $fh ,"<","file.txt" or die "error opening $!";
my @ar = <$fh>;
print pop @ar;
```

Comment: Reading the whole file into an array, just to pop the last line seems wasteful to me.

Comment: @Sobrique Yep its correct it is more memory consume. I give the other option by using while loop.

Comment: @mkHun Thanks, along with getting expected output, using file handler is effective too.

Answer (score 7):

## This answer does not work on Windows.

---

If this is a one-off thing, simply do a system call and use `tail`.

```
my $last_line = `tail -n 1 $filename`;
```

If you need to do this a lot, think about installing into a local-lib on the remote machine, or [fatpacking](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) File::ReadBackwards into your script before you deploy it.

Comment: Haha, it looks like we were typing the same answer at the same time. Nice call with the fatpacking.

Comment: @MattKelly actually no, this is a different solution from yours. Backticks are not the same a `system`.

Comment: You could also use the `qx` operator e.g. `my $last_line = qx!tail -n 1 $filename!;`

Comment: @simbabque I am getting below error, please suggest: 'tail' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @STJ tail command for linux not for windows. So it shows `tail' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: Ohh, I missed the basic in trouble. Please answer this question for windows.

Comment: I would expect windows with the cygwin and/or posix environments to support "tail"

Answer (score 0):

If you know something about the files (if the lines are relatively equal lengths, or if each line is at most X bytes, or whatever) you might be able to do something with seek. For example, if the last line is at most 40 bytes or so, you can do the below. If you know the file is 100 MB (using File::stat, which is core) you could average the first 10 lines and see how many bytes they are, and maybe multiply that by 5 just in case and seek back that far and then do the loop.  You might have to read 15 or 20 lines, but that's not bad.

```
open(my $input,"input2.txt")||die "can't open the file";

my $last_line;
seek ($input, -50, 2);
while(<$input>)
{
    $last_line = $_;
}

print "$last_line\n";
```

Comment: Try to use lexical file handle.

Comment: @mkHun I'm not sure what you mean. $input _is_ a lexical file handle.

Comment: Lexical file handle have thee arguments. `open my $fh,"<","filename";`. The reason of the lexical file handle is, no need to close the file.

Comment: @mkHun That's not what lexical file handle means. Lexical just means not global in scope, which my $input is. The second argument is optional. It's perfectly valid and correct Perl. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

Answer (score -1):

I found the following [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=255837).

Try this on for size:

```
system tail => -1 => $file;
```

Comment: `system` [returns the exit code](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) of the program it runs, **not the output**.