# Copy bottom rows from large text file in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, bigdata, text-files

I have scoured the interwebs looking for a VBA solution to the problem below to no avail. My text files range in the 3-5 million lines (this varies from text file to text file) of data but I only need to extract the last 12 lines of actual data and put into an Excel sheet, preferably delimited by spaces and tabs. Obviously, I cannot load the text file straight into Excel with a million or so row limit and using DataTypes.Add does not favor any better.

Is there a way to import these last few lines of data to Excel in a delimited fashion? My data looks something like this

### From text file:

Blah blah blah stuff I don't need for 5 million lines

Line5550203:

Line5550204: This is the title of this section of data

Line5550205:

Line5550206: Title of data 1   Title of Data 2   Title of data 3

Line5550207:

Line5550208: Units of data 1   Units of Data 2   Units of data 3

Line5550209:

Line5550210: Data1             Data2             Data 3

Line5550211:

Line5550212: Title of next section of data

Line5550213:

Line5550214: Title of Data 1a  Title of Data 2a Title of Data 3a

Line5550215:

Line5550216: Units of Data 1a  Units of Data 2a Units of Data 3a

Line5550217:

Line5550218: Data 1a   Data 2a   Data 3a

### End of file

Obviously, I don't want to import the empty lines, just the data. The titles would be optional and I don't need the units. Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it a normal .txt file or wich type of file do you have?

Comment: Hi snenson, yes, it is a normal .txt file.

Comment: And would it be ok that the lines are in 12 different cells?

Comment: Yes, once I get it into Excel, I can manipulate it easily.

Comment: Can u uploud one of these files? It should be very easy to get them, but the filesize could be a problem.

Comment: I can upload a dummy of it yes. The real data is proprietary. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command

Comment: Thank you al for the quick answers! I will try them out tomorrow and let you know what works best!

Comment: Thank you all! I don't care what anyone else says about you, y'all are alright. FunThomas won out for my uses but I appreciate everyone's responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For speed reasons, we want to avoid reading the whole file only to finally find the last rows.

You can use the `seek`-function to read from any position of a file. However, as the lines can have different lengths, we don't know the exact position. The following code assumes a maximum line length and calculate how much bytes we need to read at max. Those bytes are read into a buffer and the buffer is split into lines. Now we probably will have to many lines, but it's easy to get only the last *n* of them:

```
Sub readfileTail(filename As String, Optional maxLines As Long = 12)

    Const maxLineLen = 256
    
    Dim f As Integer
    f = FreeFile
    Open filename For Binary As #f
    
    Dim fileLen As Long, filePos As Long
    fileLen = LOF(f)        ' Get size of file in bytes.
    filePos = fileLen - (maxLines * maxLineLen)
    
    Dim buffer As String
    Seek #f, filePos
    buffer = Input((maxLines * maxLineLen), #f) ' Read character.
    
    Dim lines() As String, i As Long, startline As Long
    lines = Split(buffer, vbCrLf)
        
    startline = UBound(lines) - maxLines + 1
    If startline < 0 Then startline = 0
    
    For i = startline To UBound(lines)
        Debug.Print i, lines(i)
    Next i
    Close #f
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```vb
Sub LastFewLines()
    
    Const BUFFER As Long = 15 'last how many lines
    
    Dim fso As Object, t, n As Long, ln, arr(0 To BUFFER), i As Long
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    
    'create the dummy text file
'    Set t = fso.createtextfile("C:\Temp\dummy.txt")
'    For n = 1 To 4000000#
'        t.writeline "This is line " & n
'    Next n
'    t.Close

    Set t = fso.opentextfile("C:\Temp\dummy.txt", 1)
    
    n = 0
    Do While Not t.atendofstream
        ln = t.readline
        arr(n Mod BUFFER) = ln 'store lines, overwriting as we go
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    t.Close

    'read out last lines in correct order
    For i = (n - BUFFER) To n - 1
        Debug.Print arr(i Mod BUFFER)
    Next i
    
End Sub
```